# Can someone help me to read this seal (Characters identified: 熙熙春物見昇平)

Tags: character-identification, seal

[image]

This is a small bronze seal.
Is this phrase from a poetic or philosophic text?

Comment: i suspected it’s in kanji, japanese related.

Comment: @水巷孑蠻 it’s Chinese ^o^

Comment: the bottom strokes of 見 & 平 are distorted excessively, the “ditto” is, well, unnoticeable 

Answer (score 2):

The characters are

<kbd>[image: transcription into regular script]</kbd>

which in today's standard would be rendered as 「熙熙春物見昇平」, roughly translating to

> *the harmonious spring scenery greets peace and tranquility*

This is probably a line from the poem 《寒食輦下》 (*The Imperial Capital during the [Cold food festival](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cold_Food_Festival)*) by the [Northern Sòng](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Song_dynasty#Northern_Song,_960%E2%80%931127) poet 曹組.

---

Some notes on character identification:

- 「熙」 uses the full form of semantic 「火」 as opposed to 「灬」.
- The second 「熙」 is represented by an [iteration mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iteration_mark#Chinese) in the form of two horizontal lines ([Unicode U+16FE3](https://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U16FE0.pdf)) written to the lower-right corner of the first 「熙」.
- 「春」 ([Baxter-Sagart OC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstructions_of_Old_Chinese#Baxter%E2%80%93Sagart_(2014)): **/*tʰun/**, *spring*) is written with one of the original forms 「旾」, from doubly semantic and phonetic 「屯」 (**/*[d]ˤun/**, [*picture of sprouting plants*](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=120)) and semantic 「日」 (*sun*).
- In 「昇」, 「升」 appears as the [Shuōwén](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi) [small seal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_seal_script) form

  <kbd>[篆](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_seal_script)
  [image: 升]
  [斗部](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&file=77392&page=82)
  [說文解字](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi)</kbd>

  and corresponds to the same style for 「昇」:

  <kbd>篆
  [image: 昇]
  [日部](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&file=77390&page=97)
  說文解字</kbd>
- 「平」 appears as the Shuōwén small seal form 「」:

  <kbd>篆
  [image]
  [亏部](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&file=77390&page=31)
  說文解字</kbd>
  <kbd>[隸定](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hk/%E9%9A%B6%E5%AE%9A)
  [image]</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

熙春物見昇平 Bright spring enviroment indicates a peaceful atmosphere.

[image]